# When transforming textures (drawn as flat 3D objects) to mimic depth, black lines appear randomly

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, shader

We are developing a top-down RPG using XNA. Recently we bumped into a setback when writing the code to display our maps. When drawing the map, top-down view with a normal transformation matrix, everything seems to be fine. When using a non-flat transformation matrix, such as squeezing the top or bottom to mimic depth, black lines (rows when top or bottom, column when left or right is squeezed) that move around when the camera changes position, appear. The movement and placement appear to be random. (Image provided further down.)

## **Background information**

The maps consist of tiles. The original texture has tiles consisting of 32x32 pixels. We draw the tiles by creating 2 triangles and displaying part of the original texture on these triangles. A shader does this for us. There are three layers of triangles. First we draw all the opaque tiles and all opaque pixels of all semi-opaque and partial-transparent tiles, then all the semi-opaque and partial-transparent tiles and pixels. This works fine (but when we zoom by a floating point factor, sometimes color-blended lines are in between tile rows and/or columns).

### *Renderstates*

We use the same rasterizerState for all tiles and we switch between two when drawing solid or semi-transparent tiles.

```
_rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
_rasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.CullCounterClockwiseFace;

_solidDepthState = new DepthStencilState();
_solidDepthState.DepthBufferEnable = true;
_solidDepthState.DepthBufferWriteEnable = true;

_alphaDepthState = new DepthStencilState();
_alphaDepthState.DepthBufferEnable = true;
_alphaDepthState.DepthBufferWriteEnable = false;
```

In the shade we set the SpriteBlendMode as follows:

The first solid layer 1 uses

```
AlphaBlendEnable = False; 
SrcBlend = One; 
DestBlend = Zero;
```

All the other solid and transparent layers (drawn later) use

```
AlphaBlendEnable = True; 
SrcBlend = SrcAlpha;
DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;
```

Other shaders use this too. The `SpriteBatch` for the `SpriteFonts` used, uses default setting.

### *Generated Texture*

Some tiles are generated on the fly and saved to file. The file is loaded when the map is loaded. This is done using a `RenderTarget` created as follows:

```
RenderTarget2D rt = new RenderTarget2D(sb.GraphicsDevice, 768, 1792, false, 
    SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None);
    sb.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rt);
```

When generated, the file is saved and loaded (so we don't lose it when the device resets, because it no longer will be on a `RenderTarget`). I tried using mipmapping, but it is a spritesheet. There is no information on where tiles are placed, so mipmapping is useless and it didn't solve the problem.

### *Vertices*

We loop through every position. No floating points here yet, but position is a Vector3 (Float3).

```
for (UInt16 x = 0; x < _width;  x++)
{
    for (UInt16 y = 0; y < _heigth; y++)
    {
        [...]
        position.z = priority; // this is a byte 0-5
```

To position the tiles the following code is used:

```
tilePosition.X = position.X;
tilePosition.Y = position.Y + position.Z;
tilePosition.Z = position.Z;
```

As you know, floats are 32 bit, with 24 bits for precision. The maximum bit value of z is 8 bits (5 = 00000101). The maximum values for X and Y are 16 bits resp. 24 bits. I assumed nothing could go wrong in terms of floating points.

```
this.Position = tilePosition;
```

When the vertices are set, it does so as follows (so they all share the same tile position)

```
Vector3[] offsets  = new Vector3[] { Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Right, 
    Vector3.Right + (this.IsVertical ? Vector3.Forward : Vector3.Up), 
    (this.IsVertical ? Vector3.Forward : Vector3.Up) };
Vector2[] texOffset = new Vector2[] { Vector2.Zero, Vector2.UnitX, 
    Vector2.One, Vector2.UnitY };

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    SetVertex(out arr[start + i]);
    arr[start + i].vertexPosition = Position + offsets[i];

    if (this.Tiles[0] != null)
        arr[start + i].texturePos1 += texOffset[i] * this.Tiles[0].TextureWidth;
    if (this.Tiles[1] != null)
        arr[start + i].texturePos2 += texOffset[i] * this.Tiles[1].TextureWidth;
    if (this.Tiles[2] != null)
        arr[start + i].texturePos3 += texOffset[i] * this.Tiles[2].TextureWidth;
}
```

### *Shader*

The shader can draw animated tiles and static tiles. Both use the following sampler state:

```
sampler2D staticTilesSampler = sampler_state { 
    texture = <staticTiles> ; magfilter = POINT; minfilter = POINT; 
    mipfilter = POINT; AddressU = clamp; AddressV = clamp;};
```

The shader doesn't set any different sampler states, we also don't in our code.

Every pass, we clip at the alpha value (so we don't get black pixels) using the following line

```
clip(color.a - alpha)
```

Alpha is 1 for solid layer 1, and *almost* 0 for any other layer. This means that if there is a fraction of alpha, it will be drawn, unless on the bottom layer (because we wouldn't know what to do with it).

### *Camera*

We use a camera to mimic lookup from top down at the tiles, making them appear flat, using the z value to layer them by external layering data (the 3 layers are not always in the right order). This also works fine. The camera updates the transformation matrix. If you are wondering why it has some weird structure like this.AddChange - the code is Double Buffered (this also works). The transformation matrix is formed as follows:

```
// First get the position we will be looking at. Zoom is normally 32
Single x = (Single)Math.Round((newPosition.X + newShakeOffset.X) * 
    this.Zoom) / this.Zoom;
Single y = (Single)Math.Round((newPosition.Y + newShakeOffset.Y) * 
    this.Zoom) / this.Zoom;

// Translation
Matrix translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-x, -y, 0);

// Projection
Matrix obliqueProjection = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0,
                                      0, 1, 1, 0,
                                      0, -1, 0, 0,
                                      0, 0, 0, 1);

Matrix taper = Matrix.Identity; 

// Base it of center screen
Matrix orthographic = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
    -_resolution.X / this.Zoom / 2, 
     _resolution.X / this.Zoom / 2, 
     _resolution.Y / this.Zoom / 2, 
    -_resolution.Y / this.Zoom / 2, 
    -10000, 10000);

// Shake rotation. This works fine       
Matrix shakeRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(
    newShakeOffset.Z > 0.01 ? newShakeOffset.Z / 20 : 0);

// Projection is used in Draw/Render
this.AddChange(() => { 
    this.Projection = translation * obliqueProjection * 
    orthographic * taper * shakeRotation; });
```

## *Reasoning and Flow*

There are 3 layers of tile data. Each tile is defined by `IsSemiTransparent`. When a tile is `IsSemiTransparent`, it needs to be drawn after something not `IsSemiTransparent`. Tile data is stacked when loaded on a `SplattedTile` instance. So, even if layer one of tile data is empty, layer one of the `SplattedTile` will have tile data in the first layer, (given that at least one layer has tile data).  The reason is that the `Z-buffer` doesn't know what to blend with if they are drawn in order, since there might be no solid pixels behind it.

The layers do NOT have a z value, individual tile data has. When it is a ground tile, it has `Priority = 0`. So tiles with the same `Priority` we be ordered on layer (draw order) and opaqueness (semi-transparent, after opaque). Tiles with different priority will be drawn according to their priority.

The first solid layer has no destination pixels, so I set it to `DestinationBlend.Zero`. It also doesn't need `AlphaBlending`, since there is nothing to alphablend with. The other layers (5, 2 solid, 3 transparent) might be drawn when there is already color data and need to blend accordingly.

Before iterating through the 6 passes, the `projection matrix` is set. When using no taper, this works. When using a taper, it doesn't.

## **The Problem**

We want to mimic some more depth by applying the taper, using the some matrix. We tried several values but this is an example:

```
new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 1, 0, 0.1f,
           0, 0, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 1);
```

The screen (everything with height value 0, all flat stuff) will be squeezed. The lower the y (higher on the screen), the more it's squeezed. This actually works, but now random black lines appear almost everywhere. It seems to exclude a few tiles, but I don't see what's the correlation. We think it might had something to do with interpolation or mipmaps.

And here is an image to show you what I am talking about:
[image: Screenshot with lines].

The tiles not affected seem to be static tiles NOT on the bottom layer. **However, transparent tiles on top of those show other graphical artifacts. They miss lines (so rows just get deleted).** I marked this text because I think it is a hint to what's happening. The **vertical** lines appear if I put the `mip mag and minfilter` to `Linear`.

Here is an image zoomed in (in game zoom), showing the artifact on tiles on layer 2 or 3
[image: Screenshot with lines, zoomed in]

## **We already tried**

- `mipfilter` on `Point` or `Linear`
- Setting `GenerateMipMaps` on the original textures
- Setting `GenerateMipMaps` on the generated textures (true flag constructor of `RenderTarget`)
- Turning on mipmapping (only gave more artifacts when zoomed out, because I was [mipmapping a spritesheet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/09/08/texture-filtering.aspx).
- Not drawing layer 2 and 3 (this actually makes ALL the tiles have black lines)
- `DepthBufferEnable = false`
- Setting all solid layers to `SrcBlend = One;` `DestBlend = Zero;`
- Setting all solid layers to `ScrBlend = SrcAlpha;` `DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;`
- Not drawing transparent layer (lines are still there).
- Removing `clip(opacity)` in the `shader`. This only removes some lines. We are investigating this further.
- Searching for the same problem on msdn, stackoverflow and using google (with no luck).

Does anyone recognize this problem? On a final note, we do call the `SpriteBatch` AFTER drawing the tiles, and use another `Shader` for avatars (show no problems, because they have height > 0). Does this undo our `sampler state`? Or...?

Comment: Sorry, the system wiki's after a certain number of edits.  Unwiki'd.

Comment: I read about it on meta, thanks @Will changing it back to me. Perhaps when it's solved ;).

Comment: @Derk-Jan: Any chance you can post your code somewhere as it will be easier to help debug when we can view it directly?

Comment: @Neil, we will put a build featuring this problem only on the web.

Comment: @Neil, [here](http://dev.maxmaton.com/stackoverflow/) you go

Comment: This really looks like [z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering); but you disabled the ZBuffer - strange...

Comment: I am not sure if [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsteed/archive/2004/08/05/directly-mapping-texels-to-pixels.aspx) is related, but give it a look...

Comment: @Derk-JanKarrenbeld would you mind updating us with your findings? I assume you found the cause?

Comment: @JonathanDickinson both links didn't prove to be helpful, but thank you for trying. We have found the cause little over a month ago. I will answer the question later this night.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson answered it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem has to do with numeric types in HLSL.**

First, let's clean up that shader. I will do so, because this is how we found the actual problem. Here is a unified diff for SplattedTileShader.fx before the taperfix was put in:

```
@@ -37,76 +37,31 @@
    data.Position = mul(worldPosition, viewProjection);

-   
     return data;
 }

-float4 PixelLayer1(VertexShaderOutput input, uniform float alpha) : COLOR0
+float4 PixelLayer(VertexShaderOutput input, uniform uint layer, uniform float alpha) : COLOR0
 {
-   if(input.TextureInfo[0] < 1)
+   if(input.TextureInfo[0] < layer)
        discard;

-    float4 color;
+   float4 color;
+   float2 coord;
+   if(layer == 1)
+       coord = input.TexCoord1;
+   else if(layer == 2)
+       coord = input.TexCoord2;
+   else if(layer == 3)
+       coord = input.TexCoord3;

-   switch (input.TextureInfo[1])
+   switch (input.TextureInfo[layer])
    {
        case 0:
-           color = tex2D(staticTilesSampler, input.TexCoord1);
+           color = tex2D(staticTilesSampler, coord);
            break;
        case 1:
-           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord1);
+           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord);
            break;
        case 2:
-           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord1 + float2(frame, 0) * animOffset) * (1 - frameBlend) + tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord1 + float2(nextframe, 0) * animOffset) * frameBlend;
-           break;
-   }
-
-   clip(color.a - alpha);
-
-   return color;
-}
-
-float4 PixelLayer2(VertexShaderOutput input, uniform float alpha) : COLOR0
-{
-   if(input.TextureInfo[0] < 2)
-       discard;
-
-    float4 color;
-
-   switch (input.TextureInfo[2])
-   {
-       case 0:
-           color = tex2D(staticTilesSampler, input.TexCoord2);
-           break;
-       case 1:
-           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord2);
-           break;
-       case 2: 
-           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord2 + float2(frame, 0) * animOffset) * (1 - frameBlend) + tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord2 + float2(nextframe, 0) * animOffset) * frameBlend;
-           break;
-   }
-
-   clip(color.a - alpha);
-
-   return color;
-}
-
-float4 PixelLayer3(VertexShaderOutput input, uniform float alpha) : COLOR0
-{
-   if(input.TextureInfo[0] < 3)
-       discard;
-
-    float4 color;
-
-   switch (input.TextureInfo[3])
-   {
-       case 0:
-           color = tex2D(staticTilesSampler, input.TexCoord3);
-           break;
-       case 1:
-           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord3);
-           //color = float4(0,1,0,1);
-           break;
-       case 2:
-           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord3 + float2(frame, 0) * animOffset) * (1 - frameBlend) + tex2D(autoTilesSampler, input.TexCoord3 + float2(nextframe, 0) * animOffset) * frameBlend;
+           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord + float2(frame, 0) * animOffset) * (1 - frameBlend) + tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord + float2(nextframe, 0) * animOffset) * frameBlend;
            break;
    }
@@ -125,5 +80,5 @@
        DestBlend = Zero;
         VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VertexShaderFunction();
-        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer1(1);
+        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer(1,1);
     }

@@ -134,5 +89,5 @@
        DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VertexShaderFunction();
-        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer2(0.00001);
+        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer(2,0.00001);
    }

@@ -143,5 +98,5 @@
        DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VertexShaderFunction();
-        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer3(0.00001);
+        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer(3,0.00001);
    }
 }
@@ -155,5 +110,5 @@
        DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;
         VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VertexShaderFunction();
-        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer1(0.000001);
+        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer(1,0.000001);
     }

@@ -164,5 +119,5 @@
        DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VertexShaderFunction();
-        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer2(0.000001);
+        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer(2,0.000001);
    }

@@ -173,5 +128,5 @@
        DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VertexShaderFunction();
-        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer3(0.00001);
+        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelLayer(3,0.00001);
    }
 }
```

`

As you can see there is a new input variable called layer (type = uint). And there is now one PixelLayer function instead of three.

Next is the unified diff for SplattedTileVertex.cs

```
@@ -11,5 +11,5 @@
     {
         internal Vector3 vertexPosition;
-        internal byte textures;
+        internal float textures;
         /// <summary>
         /// Texture 0 is static tiles
@@ -17,7 +17,7 @@
         /// Texture 2 is animated autotiles
         /// </summary>
-        internal byte texture1;
-        internal byte texture2;
-        internal byte texture3;
+        internal float texture1;
+        internal float texture2;
+        internal float texture3;
         internal Vector2 texturePos1;
         internal Vector2 texturePos2;
@@ -27,8 +27,8 @@
         (
             new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
-            new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Byte4, VertexElementUsage.PointSize, 0),
-            new VertexElement(16, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0),
-            new VertexElement(24, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 1),
-            new VertexElement(32, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 2)
+            new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.PointSize, 0),
+            new VertexElement(28, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0),
+            new VertexElement(36, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 1),
+            new VertexElement(44, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 2)
         );
```

Yes, we changed the types!

And now the problems come to light. It seems that, because of the way the input is processed, the floats will never be exactly the same as the integer value. The reasoning behind this goes beyond this thread, but maybe I should make a community wiki on it.

**So, what was happening?**

Ok, so we used to discard the values that were not on the layer `(if input.TextureInfo[0] < layer -> discard)`. Inside input.TextInfo[layer] there is a float. Now we compare that float to our uint layer value. And here the magic happens. Some pixels will be just be an exact match (or maybe just above that layer value) and that would be fine, code-wise, if the type was an (u)int, but it's not.

So how to fix it? Well go with that halfway there is probably there rule. The moving code renders a pixel on a tile, if it's halfway there. We do the same thing with the layers.

Here is the fix (unified diff) for SplattedTileShader.fx

```
@@ -42,28 +42,24 @@
 float4 PixelLayer(VertexShaderOutput input, uniform uint layer, uniform float alpha) : COLOR0
 {
-   if(input.TextureInfo[0] < layer)
+   if(input.TextureInfo[0] < (float)layer - 0.5)
        discard;

    float4 color;
    float2 coord;
-   if(layer == 1)
+   if(layer < 1.5)
        coord = input.TexCoord1;
-   else if(layer == 2)
+   else if(layer < 2.5)
        coord = input.TexCoord2;
-   else if(layer == 3)
+   else
        coord = input.TexCoord3;

-   switch (input.TextureInfo[layer])
-   {
-       case 0:
-           color = tex2D(staticTilesSampler, coord);
-           break;
-       case 1:
-           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord);
-           break;
-       case 2:
-           color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord + float2(frame, 0) * animOffset) * (1 - frameBlend) + tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord + float2(nextframe, 0) * animOffset) * frameBlend;
-           break;
-   }
+   float type = input.TextureInfo[layer];
+
+   if (type < 0.5)
+       color = tex2D(staticTilesSampler, coord);
+   else if (type < 1.5)
+       color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord);
+   else
+       color = tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord + float2(frame, 0) * animOffset) * (1 - frameBlend) + tex2D(autoTilesSampler, coord + float2(nextframe, 0) * animOffset) * frameBlend;

    clip(color.a - alpha);
```

Now all the types are correct. The code works as it should, and the problem is solved. It had nothing todo with the `discard(...)` code, what I initially pointed at.

Thanks everyone that participated in helping us solve this.

Comment: I wish I could give you the bounty - but SE forces you to reward the bounty in (I think) 2 weeks. Glad to know you finally came right!

Comment: @JonathanDickinson haha, thanks. I don't really care about the bounty, but I do care about the solution :). Took us a while alright.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the rock of the bottom of that last image - it's got sandy-colored lines going through it.  Presumably, you are drawing the sand first, then the rock on top.

This tells me it's not "black lines being drawn" through the textures, but that parts of the textures are not being drawn.  Since it happens when you stretch vertically, this almost certainly means you are creating a mapping from old pixels to new pixels, without interpolating values inbetween in the new texture.

For instance, using the mapping `(x,y) --> (x, 2y)`, the points will get mapped like `(0,0) --> (0,0)`, `(0,1) --> (0,2)`, and `(0,2) --> (0, 4)`.  Notice that no points in the source texture map to `(0,1)` or `(0,3)`.  This would cause the background to seep through.  I bet if you change it to stretch horizonally, you'll see vertical lines.

What you would need to do is map the other way:  given each pixel in the target texture, find its value in the source image using the inverse of the above transformation.  You will probably get fractional values pixel-coordinates, so you will want to interpolate values.

I am not familiar at all with XNA, but there is probably a more convenient way to do this than by hand.

Comment: The fact that I can walk UNDER black lines (and they fill with character pixels) already gave me that idea. That is why I never said black lines are drawn. It is more likely that pixel rows are clipped or lost. I don't know. _Sand_ has `priority 0` (bottom layer). _Rock_ has `priority 1`. _Top of Rock_ has `priority 2`. So yes, your assumption is correct. Yes you see vertical lines if you stretch it horizontally. Isn't the pixel shader supposed to do this interpolation? Do you know how to do this in HLSL?

Comment: Look at this [transformed texture on 3d models](http://www.haik-lorenz.de/dmr.jpg). Why doesn't it have lines, but it's mapped?

Comment: Just read about [filtering by Shawn Hargreaves](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/09/08/texture-filtering.aspx). We use a built-in function, so this should happen automatically (min, we are scaling down, right?).

Comment: I am going to have to bounty this answer. Well-earned.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson, it's a great informative post, but has nothing to do with the problem at hand, nor anything towards the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I can't figure out why the black lines are appearing, but I can give you another way to render the landscape that could result in it looking correct (and, hopefully, give you a little speed boost).

### Sprites

You will need a [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) (a.k.a. sprite sheet) for this to work. You could split your altas into multiple atlases and use multi-texturing.

### Vertex Buffer

What I would do is scratch the SpriteBatch, you always know where your sprites are going to be - create a `VertexBuffer` at startup (possibly one per layer) and use it to draw the layers. Something like this (*this is a 2D buffer, it just 'looks' 3d like yours*):

[image: Vertex Buffer Sample]

The vertex definition would probably consist of:

- Position (`Vector2`)
- Texture Coordinate (`Vector2`)
- Color (`Vector4/Color`)

Each time the landscape needs to be 'cycled' (more on this later) you would go through the map under the camera and update the texture co-ordinates and/or color in the `VertexBuffer`. Don't refresh the buffer each frame. I wouldn't send the texture co-ordinates to the GPU in `[0, 1]` range, rather `[0, Number of Sprites]` - calculate the `[0, 1]` in your vertex shader.

*Important:* Don't share vertices (i.e. use an `IndexBuffer`) because the vertices that are shared by more than two faces need to remain distinct (they have distinct texture co-ordinates) - build up the buffer as though `IndexBuffer`s didn't exist. Using an `IndexBuffer` is wasteful in this scenario, so just stick with a `VertexBuffer` alone.

### Rendering

The world matrix you use will map `[0, 1]` to the size of the screen plus the size of a tile (i.e. a simple scale `x = Viewport.Width + 32` and `y = Viewport.Height + 32`). Your projection matrix would be an identity matrix.

The view matrix is tricky. Imagine that your map is looking at a current block of the tiles (which it is) at `{0,0}`, what you need to do is figure out the offset (in pixels) from that where your camera is looking. So essentially it will be an offset matrix with `x = Camera.X - LeftTile.X * (Viewport.Width / NumTiles.X)` and similar for `y`.

The matrices are the only tricky bit, once you have them set up it's a simple `DrawUserPrimitives()` call and you are done.

Note that this only deals with your landscape, draw your other sprites as you are today.

### Landscape Cycling

When the position of your camera changes, you basically need to determine if it's looking at a new block of tiles and update the `VertexBuffer`s appropriately (texture co-ordinates and color - leave the position alone, no need to recalculate it).

### Alternatively

Another option is to render each layer to a `RenderTarget2D` and use your current transformation once against the entire layer. This would either resolve your problem, or, it would make the real reason very apparrant.

*Side note: I would provide sample code if it wasn't 00h40 here, this question deserves it. I'll see how much time I have tomorrow night.*

Comment: Thank you for your time to write this post. Few things: 1. with this approach I can't simply trow in 3D models, 2. The rendering part is essentially the exact same thing as my transformation matrix. 3. We already use spritesheetS <-- multiple.

Answer (score 2):

With what you've given us, I would be **extremely** suspicious of your layering code. This really looks like the bottom layer is **sometimes** poking through the layers that are supposed to be on top and hiding them, depending on floating point rounding. Stripes perpendicular to the viewing angle is a very common effect when you have two triangles which are supposed to be exactly coplanar, but for whatever reason don't have exactly the same vertex coordinates (e.g. one is bigger than the other). What happens if you draw the various layers a very very small amount apart from each other? Like, draw the bottom solid layer at -0.00002, and the next at -0.00001, and the top layer at 0 exactly (assuming all three are being drawn at 0 now).

I don't know about XNA specifically but the layering issue is always a fundamental problem of using floating point to represent geometry, and I would be surprised if XNA "magically" avoids it for you. Not sure why some of the tiles are fine but most are screwed. Probably those tiles just got lucky, or something. Problems caused by floating point error often act very strange like this.

If separating the layers slightly doesn't help, then you're pretty much reduced to standard comment-based debugging; try it with no sprites, with no animated tiles, with no transparent layer, &c. When it stops happening, whatever you just commented out is breaking it :P

Comment: **1**. if _sometimes_ was the case, wouldn't that be happening without transformation as well?  
**2**. I will update my post to show the positioning of the tiles. Each layered tile is on the EXACT same spot (share the same memory in c#, before assigned in separate addresses in the GPU). No movement possible.  
**3**. I will try the layering proposal with small amounts you gave me.

Comment: I placed the layering code. As you can see, different priorities are drawn at different z values. I am still going to try what you suggested, but even if that were the case, there should be less tiles with lines, since on a good deal of positions, the layers ARE actually on different z values. Also, every tile is EXACTLY 32x32 pixels. This is set. No variables.

Comment: Ok, I tried not drawing layer 2 and 3. Now the rows are complete from left to right, not showing gaps. So unaffected tiles are solid tiles on layer 2 or 3. Partially solid tiles (so transparant tiles etc) DO show the lines, making rows of pixels dissappear.

Comment: @Derk if it is a depth-fighting issue, as Paul suggests, are you able to turn off depth-reads? (`DepthBufferEnable = false`). To do this you'll have to depth-sort your geometry yourself, instead of relying on the depth-buffer.

Comment: @Andrew When i draw only one layer, I eliminated that case. But to satisfy you and me, I am able to turn it off and setting it to DepthBufferEnable = false will only screw up some shadows and sprites order, not remove the lines. This is the expected behavior to my knowledge. I will add your suggestion to the tried list.

Comment: @Derk-Jan: What `SpriteBlendMode` are you using?

Comment: @Neil The first solid layer 1 uses `AlphaBlendEnable = False;`, `SrcBlend = One;`, `DestBlend = Zero;`. All the other solid and transparent layers (drawn later) use `AlphaBlendEnable = True;`, `SrcBlend = SrcAlpha;`, `DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;`. Other shaders use this too. The `SpriteBatch` for the `SpriteFont`s used, uses default settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your SplattedTileShader.fx shader.

The black lines appears because the discarded pixels.

is difficult to follow your shader code without more info, but the problem is there.

i think that the way you are doing multitexture is too complicated.

maybe it will be easier to make a shader that support multitexture in one pass.

in your vertex you can pass four weight values for each texture and do the mix by yourself in the shader.

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Multitexturing.php

Comment: This was indeed the case, but you don't seem to explain anything in your response. Which pixels are you talking about? And more info? I practically explained every line of code. What else would you like to know? 

Thank you for the link though, will look into it!

Comment: umm... the discarded pixels are discarded with clip sentence... you can comment clip sentences and it will be draw not right, but better. And your shader code it's not well explained, I did not understand what it was doing.

Comment: No, that part works correctly. The shader is clipping all pixels that aren't visible. Plus drawing each of the three layers. First opaque pixels, then (semi)transparent pixels.

Comment: this makes me wonder if you read the post completely. Yes we did: - Removing clip(opacity) in the shader. This only removes some lines. We are investigating this further. In the end, didn't do shizzle, because it wasn't the problem!

Comment: clip did not work correctly, the problem was there because you was working with corrupted data... you only had to follow the thread...  and no, i had not seen your post...